# Подскажите, как перенести всю структуру дерева со всеми коммитами в новую ветку?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

Есть такая структура коммитов гита:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

От первого коммита (df46d78) отходит ветка "git+github_by_itdoctor", в которой пока нет никаких коммитов. Задача заключается в том, чтобы всю структуру, начиная с коммита 1cb776b перенести в эту ветку (с сохранением структуры и коммитов) и в итоге чтобы ветка master оказалась полностью чиста. Я вроде понимаю, что надо cherry-pick использовать, но как именно - ума не приложу. И конечно, скорее всего возникнут конфликты, но это уже совсем другая история.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `git reset --hard` два раза с одного места на другое. Будет своп указателей веток. Или я неправильно вас понял.

Comment: Скорее всего что не так поняли. Имелось ввиду "вырезать" всю структуру дерева (с коммитами) от коммита 1cb776b (включительно) и выше и всё это "вставить" в новую ветку "git+github_by_itdoctor".

Comment: `reset` у master как раз и будет вырезание. А `reset` у новой - будет как раз вставка.

Comment: Наверное, я все-таки не понял... в каком коммите/ветке надо находиться для первого "git reset --hard" и где для второго?

Comment: `git checkout master` , `git reset --hard df46d78` - перенос master назад

Comment: `git checkout git+github_by_itdoctor` , `git reset --hard 109335e` - новую ветку вперёд.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Огромное спасибо! Вроде как получилось!!!

Comment: а что с удалёнными будете делать?

Comment: ну, я в гите полный новичек, наверное удалю и сделаю заново... в любом случае это у меня учебный проект (именно посвящен изучению гита). Хотя подсознание подсказывает, что есть какой-то более "гуманный" способ сделать правильно.(?)

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout git+github_by_itdoctor` - переходим в ветку `git+github_by_itdoctor`

- `git merge master`

или так :

- `git reset --hard 109335e` - переносим эту ветку на место `master`

потом

- `git checkout master` - переходим в ветку `master`
- `git reset --hard df46d78` - переносим грубо ветку `master` на первый коммит.

В итоге вы поменяете место веток друг у друга.